# Copy worksheets after a specific worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has a dynamic number of worksheets within it. The relevant worksheets I want to extract always occur after the worksheet "Sheet 3". The problem is the relevant worksheets have dynamic names e.g. "Apple-A", "Orange-1", etc. and I wanted to create a code that will always copy every sheet after "Sheet 3" regardless of their naming convention.

To this point I have only been able to copy sheets when specifically calling its name e.g.

```
total = Workbooks("Fruits.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
Workbooks("Fruits").Worksheets("Apple-A").Copy_after:=Workbooks("Fruits.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
```

Is there a method for copying a number of sheets to a new workbook after a certain worksheet name is called?

Comment: If you want to use the third sheet, no matter the name, you can use `Workbooks("Fruits.xlsm").Sheets(3).Range("A1")...` which will do something with `A1` from the third (via index) worksheet.  So if you look at the worksheet tabs, from left to right, it will choose the third one.

Comment: But the sheet called "Sheet 3" may not be the third sheet ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Fruits.xlsm")
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets("Sheet 3").Index +1)
ws.Copy
```

Note:

Defining the Workbook you are operating in is always a good Idea. Next lets take a closer look at Worksheet Objects.

With `Workbook.Sheets(index/name)` you can access a worksheet at a certain position = index e.g `1 for the first sheet in the workbook` or by its name.

Now you are looking for a sheet next to a sheet of which you know the name.

`wb.Sheets("Sheet 3").Index` returns the position of `Sheet 3`. Now you want the sheet to its right. This will be at the position `wb.Sheets("Sheet 3).Index +1`.

EDIT:

I think the question has been edited to copy "all sheets following 'Sheet 3'"

The code for this:

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks("Fruits.xlsm")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Add

indexOfSheet3 = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet 3").Index

For i = indexOfSheet3 + 1 To wbSource.Sheets.Count
    wbSource.Sheets(i).Copy After:= wbTarget.Sheets(wbTarget.Sheets.Count)
Next i

'Delete the defualt sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbTarget.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I'm getting an runtime error 424, but I dont see any incorrect implementation of workbook name and dimensioned indexOfSheet3 as Long. Any other tips?

Comment: Nevermind got it! Just a correction:wbSource.Sheets(i).Copy After line

Answer (score 0):

I’d go the opposite way: copy all worksheets to a new workbook and delete its first three ones:

```
Workbooks("Fruits.xlsm").Worksheets.Copy

Dim i As Long
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 3 To 1 Step - 1
    Worksheets(i).Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: This only works, if "Sheet 3" is also at index 3 in the Workbook, which is most of the time a reasonable assumption, but not stated in the question, so I would state that in your answer.